# How to store DB data as JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

In my project, I want to put DB data to a json file. I can fetch DB data successfully, and these data should be in datagrid.json.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include("DB.php"); 
$sql="select aa,bb,cc,dd from OA where sysnum='TZ20171204173151317';";
$sel=$conn->query($sql);

$arr=array();
while($row=$sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))     
{
  $arr[]=$row;
}
$result["rows"]=$arr;

$file='datagrid.json';

file_put_contents($file, $result);

?>
```

Here is correct content of datagrid.json:

```
{"rows":[{"aa":"123.jpg","bb":".jpg","cc":"Tom","dd":"2017-12-04 17:31:51"},
     {"aa":"1.jpg","bb":".jpg","cc":"Stack","dd":"2017-12-04 17:31:56"},
     {"aa":"test.jpg","bb":".jpg","cc":"Jack","dd":"2017-12-04 17:32:00"}
]}
```

I have chmod of datagrid.json with:

```
chmod 777 datagrid.json
```

But it works fail. Datagrid.json can not be created. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You cant store an array inside a file. Instead you have to convert the array to json format using [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
<?php
include("DB.php"); 
$sql="select aa,bb,cc,dd from OA where sysnum='TZ20171204173151317';";
$sel=$conn->query($sql);

$arr=array();
while($row=$sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))     
{
  $arr[]=$row;
}
$result["rows"]=$arr;

$file='datagrid.json';

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($result)); // Convert to json before saving

?>
```

Comment: the result is wrong: {"rows":[{"\u4e2d\u6587\u540d":"123.jpg","\u6587\u4ef6\u7c7b\u578b":".jpg"......}]}. I want {"rows":[{"aa":"123.jpg","bb":".jpg"......}]}

Comment: It is random. I should define 'aa'=>'123.jpg', I don't know define Multidimensional array

Comment: Is it always just those four rows? aa, bb, cc, dd?

Comment: No, rows are not fixed. Just always four columns